# tvOS load website URL

Tags: javascript, tvos, tvml, tvjs

I am new in tvOS application. i am trying to integrate custom application with TVML & TVJS. I created a page and add banner in it. My requirement is to load a webpage inside that application. I tried different methods to load a webpage using that application.js file but fails. Please help me how to load a webpage using TVML and TVJS.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you need to use `UIWebView` class but you cannot find it in the tvOS SDK (because it was removed). But you can use this class as a "private API class" (you can create an instance of this class and call methods for it, because you have enough information about `UIWebView`). It can be hard for you. If so, you can use some libraries (such as https://github.com/jvanakker/tvOSBrowser) that using the private API to make `UIWebView` available in the tvOS.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might have a hard time on getting a web browser on the TV app store, as I think apple does really see people browsing on the apple tv.

Depends on your use case,

if you are only trying to display a page, you might able to use some of the online url to picture services like https://urlbox.io/docs, or build your own server using existing browser features. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLIFrameElement/getScreenshot

If you are getting users to another services, the correct way to do is with deep link, which you can learn more about here. https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/246/

or if you are trying to transfer the view into sales, displaying a QR code is the way to go. as iOS 11 makes QR Code scanning a standard, it will be very easy for your users to scan the code. https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-use-ios-11s-hidden-qr-code-reader/